# Serialization of Access to UI Thread in MAUI

Tags: multithreading, maui, ui-thread

I am using the following code to change the text on a label outside of the UI thread.

The text on the label was not what I expected.  It took some time to realize what was happening.

```
string mystringvar = null;
mystringvar = "WHAT I WANT";
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Dispatch(() =>
{
    mylabel.Text = mystringvar;
});
mystringvar = "WHAT I GOT";
// on the UI, the text on mylabel is WHAT I GOT
```

Is there any mechanism for determining the UI is updated before I use mystringvar again?  I have not experimented, but it would make sense that this also applies to other properties of the label.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your thread completes before the UI thread updates the label hence why you see the final string value not the intermediate value.

For these types of UI synchronization issues, the easiest solution is to use async/await. If you think about it, your thread pauses whilst the UI thread updates the label, when done, your thread resumes.

```cs
// MainPage.xaml.cs ...
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void OnChangeTextClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string mystringvar = null;
        mystringvar = "WHAT I WANT";
        Debug.WriteLine($"Step 1: MyThread: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}"); // Step 1: MyThread: 10
        await MainThread.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync(() =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Step 2: MainThread: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}"); // Step 2: MainThread: 1
            mylabel.Text = mystringvar + " (Step 2)";
        });
        await Task.Delay(500);
        await MainThread.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync(() =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Step 3: MainThread: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}"); // Step 3: MainThread: 1
            mylabel.Text = mystringvar + " (Step 3)"; ;
        });
        await Task.Delay(500);
        await MainThread.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync(() =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Step 4: MainThread: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}"); // Step 4: MainThread: 1
            mylabel.Text = mystringvar + " (Step 4)"; ;
        });
        await Task.Delay(500);
        await MainThread.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync(() =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Step 5: MainThread: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}"); // Step 5: MainThread: 1
            mylabel.Text = mystringvar;
        });
        Debug.WriteLine($"Step 6: MyThread: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}"); // Step 6: MyThread: 10
        mystringvar = "WHAT I GOT (NOT!)";
    }
}
```

```xml
<!-- MainPage.xaml ... -->
<VerticalStackLayout>
    <Label x:Name="mylabel" Text="Hello, World!" />
    <Button Text="Change Text" Clicked="OnChangeTextClicked" />
</VerticalStackLayout>
```

A full version of the above code is in: https://github.com/stephenquan/StackOverflow.Maui/tree/main/StackOverflow.Maui.SyncAccess

[image: ChangeText.gif]

Alternatively, you could always take a copy and ensure that the copy is never overwritten, e.g.

```cs
string mystringvar = null;
mystringvar = "WHAT I WANT";
{
    string mystringvar2 = mystringvar;
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Dispatch(() =>
    {
        mylabel.Text = mystringvar2;
    });
}
mystringvar = "WHAT I GOT (NOT!)";
```

Comment: Thank you.  For the time being yes we made a copy as proposed.  Your proposed solution is much better, especially where serialization is essential.

Comment: Please see an update I've inserted below as an answer as it is too long to be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Either I’m missing something or the technique cited by Stephen Quan above does not work, at least not for methods on the main page.

For example, in the following code, in mymainpage code (not shown) I’ve inserted a break point at “MethodOnMainPage”.  When I execute the following code, which is not on the main thread, all three invocations of mymainpage.InvokeOnMainThread are executed with no break point encountered.

```
await MainThread.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync(() =>
{
    mymainpage.MethodOnMainPage(argument1);
});
await MainThread.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync(() =>
{
    mymainpage.MethodOnMainPage(argument2);
});
await MainThread.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync(() =>
{
    mymainpage.MethodOnMainPage(argument3);
});
```

Then later, after the above code completes, the break point on the main thread is activated three times in succession.  This isn’t what I would expect if the invoking thread pauses whilst the UI updates.

Comment: For await to work it needs to be in an async function, please verify that by adding to your code snippet. Also, the preferred SO way to ask followup question is to actually edit your original question with supplementary information or to split to a new question.

Comment: Thank you for following up Stephen.  I can confirm that the method begins "private static async Task FunctionName(Int32 argument1, Int32 argument2, Int32 argument3)" and can also confirm that if I remove "async", the compiler throws error CS4032 reminding that "await" may be used only within an "async" method.